# NLog with Autofac in MassTransit 6.0?

Tags: c#, autofac, nlog, masstransit

My Consumers fail to instantiate from Autofac due to the following:

> Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[MyConsumer] logger' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyService, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[MyConsumer])'.

The ILoggers resolve fine in every other class except the MassTransit Consumers; I believe it's an issue with LogContext.ConfigureCurrentLogContext(); and order of operations. Below is the code, edited for brevity:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder(); // Autofac

builder.RegisterType<LoggerFactory>()
                         .As<ILoggerFactory>()
                         .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>))
                         .As(typeof(ILogger<>))
                         .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes() // load up all services, yada yada

// what to pass here? I'm inside an unbuilt Autofac Container at this point. There is no ILoggerFactory until the Container is built!
LogContext.ConfigureCurrentLogContext(); // configure MassTransit logging

builder.AddMassTransit(x => 
            {
                x.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

                x.AddBus(bus => MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
                {
                    config.ConfigureEndpoints(bus); // wire-up consumers discovered by the AddConsumers() call above
                }));
            });

Container = builder.Build(); // now build the container

// add NLog
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(Container); // this requires a built Container!
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
loggerFactory.AddNLog();
```

I should note that logging within MassTransit is actually working; I see all kind of debug output regarding the queues and messages. But the Consumer will not instantiate for whatever reason. If I try to manually `Resolve<ILogger<MyConsumer>>()` I'll get an ILogger but MassTransit seems to have trouble with it.

**Edit**: full error message via VS Output:

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyConsumer' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger 1[MyConsumer] logger' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyService, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[MyConsumer])'.*

Package versions:

- Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.1
- MassTransit 6.0
- MassTransit.Autofac 6.0
- NLog.Extensions.Logging 1.6.1

Comment: Could you share the full exception message ?

Comment: I updated it - not much to add unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cannot resolve parameter `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger 1[MyConsumer] logger`

This error message means that *Autofac* can't find a registered `Logger<MyConsumer>`. If you look at your registration you register `ILogger<>` and not `Logger<>`. You should change the dependency to the interface version in `MyConsumer` and *autofac* will find it.

Comment: Correct! Thank you! I really appreciate the second set of eyes, I completely missed that pesky "I"

Comment: It would appear that LogContext.ConfigureCurrentLogContext() isn't needed in my scenario as A) I can't pass an ILoggerFactory to it, and B) it works without the call. Not sure why but I'll take it.

Comment: Since you're using registration (`.AddMassTransit`), it tries to resolve an ILoggerFactory from the container and uses it if found. So you're all good.